# Java Hibernate refresh j table not functioning

Tags: java, hibernate, jtable

[image]

I am learning Java with Hibernate ORM and Netbeans. I am creating new application that is interacting with data from database and has few of the tables.

I made a simple PHP ajax cart to insert the data into Cart and to the Orders table, but I am unable to refresh it on jTtable inside my swing Application.

This is my Pojo model from Orders with my field and all the getters and setters :

```
 private Integer orderId;
 private Date orderDate;
 private String orderName;
 private String orderEmail;

public Orders() {
}


 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)


@Column(name="order_id", unique=true)
public Integer getOrderId() {
    return this.orderId;
}

public void setOrderId(Integer orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}
```

And the rest of the feilds...

How I am inserting data into the J table is with my populateTable void function :

```
  void populateTable(){

     DefaultTableModel m = (DefaultTableModel)tblOrders1.getModel();
     List<Orders> lista = HibernateUtil.getSession().createQuery(
            "from Orders ").list();

     m.setRowCount(0);
     Object niz[]=new Object[5];

    for (Orders s : lista) {
       niz[0]= s.getOrderId();
       niz[1]= s.getOrderName();
       niz[2]= s.getOrderEmail();


       m.addRow(niz);
       m.setValueAt(s, m.getRowCount()-1, 1);

    }
}
```

I am calling the Populate tables function inside the JPanel constructor, also I tried to apply that function to the "refresh" jButton1 action preformed event but nothing changes and It is seemed to be cached by hibernate ?

What I found out is that when I insert something or update/delete with my other crud operations inside the application the orders table does get refreshed and I don't have to restart the application to get the data.

What I am doing for now to get around this problem is inserting "logger table" in my database , and every time the orders panel is opened the date and time is  entered in the database, which resets or repopulates models and hibernate cache.

Comment: Maybe you have to refressh view, or query is not returing what you think it should.

Comment: I tried to repaint the view and the table , but it is not working. The query is returning the correct data, I know that because the table gets populated when I restart the application.